# How many qubits are simulable with a normal computer and freely accessible simulators?

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate an arbitrary isolated quantum circuit acting on $n$ qubits (i.e. a pure state of $n$ qubits).

As I know RAM is the bottleneck for quantum simulators, you can consider a "normal" computer to have between $4$ and $8$ Gio of RAM, all the other components are considered sufficiently powerful to not be the bottleneck.

With this definition of a "normal" computer,

> What is the maximum value of $n$ (the number of qubits) for which an arbitrary quantum circuit is simulable in a reasonable time ($<1\text{h}$) with a normal computer and freely accessible simulators?

Comment: You also need to specify how long you're willing to wait, since there are simulation strategies that use very little space but way more time.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about pure states?

Comment: I edited the question, I talk about pure states.

Comment: All other components are sufficiently powerful, yet you limit time? This does not make sense.

Comment: “Arbitrary quantum circuits” are arbitrarily long and so no simulator (or real quantum computer) can complete them within an hour, no matter the number of qubits.

Comment: I was able to do unitary evolutions of 21 qubits within 1hr using Microsoft Liquid about 1.5yrs ago on my desktop with 16GB of RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer doesn't directly answer the question (I have little experience of *real* simulators with practical overheads etc.), but here's a theoretical upper bound.

Let's assume that you need to store the whole state vector of $k$ qubits in memory. There are $2^n$ elements that are complex numbers. A complex number requires 2 real numbers, and a real number occupies [24 bytes in python](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609). Let's say we want to cram this into $4\times 10^9$ bytes of RAM (probably leaving a few over for your operating system etc.) Hence,
$$
48\times 2^n\leq 4\times 10^9
$$
Rearrange for $n$ and you have $n\leq26$ qubits.

Note that applying gates in a quantum circuit is relatively inexpensive memory-wise. See the "Efficiency Improvements" section in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1970/1837). From that strategy, one should be able to estimate the time it takes to apply a single one- or two-qubit gate to an $n$-qubit system, and hence how many gates you might expect to fit within some times limit (an hour is very modest, but would certainly serve for illustrative purposes).

Comment: I'd say that's a fairly accurate estimate: All the memory you need is basically the one used to store the state.

Comment: Where do those 24 bytes come from, given that a usual double has 64 bits?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I Have no idea!

Comment: Could it be that it's just not true?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch it does seem to be what is consistently claimed online for recent versions of python. There’s nothing wrong with it using 3 times as much memory as you might hope. It’s not like it’s as weird as 24 bits would be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395758/how-much-memory-is-used-by-a-numpy-ndarray  -- ???

Comment: @NorbertSchuch so presumably the add-ons can build in more efficient data structures that I didn’t take into account. In which case, you can probably add 1 to the bound.

Comment: I rather suspect that ONE double takes 24 bytes -- 8 bytes + some control structure -- while a VECTOR of doubles takes 8 bytes per double + some extra control structure.  I very much doubt it has to do with numpy, I'd rather suspect the same is true for vectors/matrices of doubles in regular python.  In any case, obviously all of these factors don't really matter much (doesn't hurt to get them correct though).

Answer (score -1):

Along with depending on time constraints, as Craig mentioned, you also need to specify how accurate/what gates you want the simulation to have. CHP (CNOT, Phase, Hadamard) simulations can do incredibly large circuits with large numbers of qubits incredible quickly, however they only allow a certain restricted gate set, so some gates, such as T gates, must be approximated.

Other simulations exist (such as quantumsim and others) which store full density matrices, and as a result are much more significantly limited in the number of qubits they work with seeing as they must store a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix.