# Finding the maximum number of Q# simulatable qubits

Tags: programming, simulation, q#

I'm new to Q# and I was curious on how one would find the number of Q# simulatable qubits for a specific machine.  I know Microsoft has an approximation of 16GB ~ 30 qubits but I wanted a better estimation for my own machines.

I wrote this quick program that runs a loop which allocates a register of increasing size.  When I get a `std::bad_alloc` error I then have an estimate.  I'm guessing there is a better way either through a tool or some pre-written code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple rule is:

> **Doubling the memory gives you one additional qubit.**

So if Microsoft says that

```
16GB -> 30 qubits
```

then

```
 8GB -> 29 qubits
 4GB -> 28 qubits
 2GB -> 27 qubits
 ...
32GB -> 31 qubits
64GB -> 32 qubits
```

and so further.

This scaling, as well as the number quoted by Microsoft, can be understood from an argument as the one in the [linked answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3862/2293), using that

1. each complex number equals 2 real numbers with double precision (8 bytes each), so 16 bytes are needed per comples number,
2. to describe $N$ qubits, $2^N$ numbers are needed,
3. and 1GB=$1024^3$ bytes

which together yields $16\cdot 2^N = x \, \mathrm{GB} = x\cdot 1024^3$ with $x$ the memory required in GB, which results in 
$$
N = \log_2(x\,\times 1024^3/16) = \log_2(x)+26\ .
$$
For $x=16$ (i.e. 16GB of memory), $\log_2(16)=4$, and this yields exactly 
$$
N=30 \ \mathrm{qubits}\ ,
$$
which is the number quoted by Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

A simple formula for the number of qubits you can simulate in almost all programs is given by [this very well received answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3862/2293).

After re-arranging the formula given there into a form that's much more relevant to your specific question, and changing 48 to 32 since Q# is written in C++, not python, we have:

$$
N_{\rm{qubits}} =  \log_2\left( \frac{\rm{RAM}}{32} \right)
$$

When $\rm{RAM} = 32\rm{GB} = 32\times 1024^3$, this formula gives 30, meaning you an simulate 30 qubits.

If you plug the amount of RAM you have, into that formula, it will give a good estimate of how many qubits you can simulate without using a more sophisticated simulator.

Comment: The Q# full state simulator is written in C++, not Python, so it takes only 16 bytes per double-precision number, or 32 bytes per complex number, not 48.
Of course, you don't get to fill in every byte of your system's memory with the state vector; there is some overhead for the OS and the rest of the .NET runtime, etc.

Comment: Why does python use so much more space for double-precision numbers ??

Comment: @AlanGeller Shouldn't double be 64 bits? This would also fit with the 16GB=30qubits quoted by the asker.

Comment: @user1271772 In which way would a "more sophisticated simulator" be able to surpass this limitation?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, of course; my brain added an extra factor of 2... 8 bytes per double, 16 bytes per complex number and thus 16 bytes per entry in the state vector.

Comment: @AlanGeller: Why does python use 24 bytes per complex number?

Comment: @user1271772 I doubt it does.

Comment: @user1271772 I doubt it does too, and in any case I suspect that the simulators written for Python are not actually implemented natively in Python, but are instead written in C or C++.

Comment: @AlanGeller In the end it's usually all matrix multiplication, which anyway calls BLAS routines regardless of the language used.