How to simulate circuit on a simulator with more than 129 qubits?
Currently I am using the Aer simulator and I get the error: CircuitTooWideForTarget: 'Number of qubits (129) in circuit-166 is greater than maximum (29) in the coupling_map'? Is there any simulator in which I can run this amount of qubits? Thanks

I general, you can't. An arbitrary superposition state for 129 qubits has approx $2^{129} = 6.8 \times 10^{38}$ probability amplitudes. Each amplitude requires around 32 bits to be stored; this means you would need ~ $4 \times 10^{39}$ bytes of memory just to store the state. See more details here for how many qubits are reasonably simulatable: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3862/8731
You can probably increase the number in the estimate given in the link by using GPUs, but 129 qubits will still be far out of reach.

If you know that the entanglement in your state is bounded, you could use tensor network states like MPS.

Thank you for your response @diemilio and Refik. I am trying to use quantum computing to iterate through an array with rows of 129 bits. So evidently I need 129 qubits. Is there any way to lower this amount to like around 29 qubits? How could I decompose this issue in smaller parts? Should I just simulate about 29 qubits at a time and add up the answers?
